# How to get specific values from XML cross join function in SQL server query

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a xml stored in t_CBResponseBatchDetail table and ResponseReceivedData column. Now each xml contains customer multiple accounts and with other details. I was able to create a separate row for each account, but I'm stuck here as I wanted to get each record separately. For example I want to create ReportedDate as a column with each records.

Below is the xml.

```
<InquiryResponseType
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<ReportData
    xmlns="xxxxx">
    <AccountDetails>
        <Account seq="1" id="1589243954" ReportedDate="2022-04-30">
            <AdditionalMFIDetails id="1589243954">
                <MFIClientFullname>USHA USHA  </MFIClientFullname>
                <MFIDOB>09-04-1982</MFIDOB>
                <MFIGender>Female</MFIGender>
                <MFIIdentification>
                    <MFIVoterID>YEE0585182</MFIVoterID>
                    <MFIUID>XXXXXXXXXXXX</MFIUID>
                </MFIIdentification>
                <MFIAddress>
                    <AdditionalAddressDetails seq="1">
                        <MFIAddressline>NA NA GRAM KHANDWABIBINA NA KHANDWABIBI NAINDIA</MFIAddressline>
                        <MFIState>MP</MFIState>
                        <MFIPostalPIN>456771</MFIPostalPIN>
                    </AdditionalAddressDetails>
                </MFIAddress>
                <Phone seq="1" typeCode="M">
                    <Number>9131880625</Number>
                </Phone>
                <Phone seq="2" typeCode="H">
                    <Number>9131880625</Number>
                </Phone>
                <MemberId>190001457575</MemberId>
            </AdditionalMFIDetails>
            <AccountNumber> 20900001190917</AccountNumber>
            <CurrentBalance>3866</CurrentBalance>
            <Institution>Fincare Small Finance Bank Limited</Institution>
            <PastDueAmount>0</PastDueAmount>
            <DisbursedAmount>35000</DisbursedAmount>
            <LoanCategory>JLG Individual</LoanCategory>
            <LoanPurpose>MICRO BUSINESS</LoanPurpose>
            <SanctionAmount>35000</SanctionAmount>
            <LastPaymentDate>2022-04-26</LastPaymentDate>
            <DateReported>2022-04-30</DateReported>
            <DateOpened>2020-01-29</DateOpened>
            <LoanCycleID>2</LoanCycleID>
            <DateApplied>2020-01-29</DateApplied>
            <AppliedAmount>35000</AppliedAmount>
            <NoOfInstallments>24</NoOfInstallments>
            <RepaymentTenure>Monthly</RepaymentTenure>
            <InstallmentAmount>1900</InstallmentAmount>
            <KeyPerson>
                <Name>RADHESHYAM</Name>
                <RelationType>Husband</RelationType>
            </KeyPerson>
            <Nominee>
                <Name>RADHESHYAM</Name>
                <RelationType>Husband</RelationType>
            </Nominee>
            <AccountStatus>Current Account</AccountStatus>
            <History24Months>
                <Month key="04-22">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="03-22">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="02-22">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="01-22">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="12-21">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="11-21">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="10-21">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="09-21">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="08-21">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="07-21">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="06-21">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="05-21">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="04-21">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="03-21">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="02-21">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="01-21">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="12-20">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="11-20">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="10-20">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="09-20">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="08-20">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="07-20">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="06-20">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="05-20">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
            </History24Months>
            <BranchIDMFI>10126</BranchIDMFI>
            <KendraIDMFI>3000008</KendraIDMFI>
            <DaysPastDue>0</DaysPastDue>
            <TypeOfInsurance>L</TypeOfInsurance>
        </Account>
        <Account seq="2" id="1604629720" ReportedDate="2022-05-04">
            <AdditionalMFIDetails id="1604629720">
                <MFIClientFullname>USHA</MFIClientFullname>
                <MFIDOB>09-04-1982</MFIDOB>
                <MFIGender>Female</MFIGender>
                <MFIIdentification>
                    <MFIVoterID>YEE0585182</MFIVoterID>
                    <MFIUID>XXXXXXXXXXXX</MFIUID>
                    <MFIOtherID>XXXXXXXX4048</MFIOtherID>
                </MFIIdentification>
                <MFIAddress>
                    <AdditionalAddressDetails seq="1">
                        <MFIAddressline>KHANDWABIBI01 UJJAIN</MFIAddressline>
                        <MFIState>MP</MFIState>
                        <MFIPostalPIN>456771</MFIPostalPIN>
                    </AdditionalAddressDetails>
                </MFIAddress>
                <Phone seq="2" typeCode="M">
                    <Number>7000931043</Number>
                </Phone>
                <Phone seq="2" typeCode="H">
                    <Number>7000931043</Number>
                </Phone>
                <MemberId>55070001601</MemberId>
            </AdditionalMFIDetails>
            <AccountNumber> 55075507P2600006031</AccountNumber>
            <CurrentBalance>2611</CurrentBalance>
            <Institution>IIFL SAMASTA FINANCE LIMITED</Institution>
            <PastDueAmount>0</PastDueAmount>
            <DisbursedAmount>20000</DisbursedAmount>
            <LoanCategory>JLG Individual</LoanCategory>
            <LoanPurpose>SMALL AND MARGINAL F</LoanPurpose>
            <SanctionAmount>20000</SanctionAmount>
            <LastPaymentDate>2022-05-04</LastPaymentDate>
            <DateReported>2022-05-04</DateReported>
            <DateOpened>2020-02-19</DateOpened>
            <LoanCycleID>1</LoanCycleID>
            <DateSanctioned>2020-02-15</DateSanctioned>
            <DateApplied>2020-02-13</DateApplied>
            <AppliedAmount>20000</AppliedAmount>
            <NoOfInstallments>52</NoOfInstallments>
            <RepaymentTenure>Bi-weekly</RepaymentTenure>
            <InstallmentAmount>480</InstallmentAmount>
            <KeyPerson>
                <Name>RADHESHYAM</Name>
                <RelationType>Husband</RelationType>
            </KeyPerson>
            <Nominee>
                <Name>RADHESHYAM</Name>
                <RelationType>Husband</RelationType>
            </Nominee>
            <AccountStatus>Current Account</AccountStatus>
            <History24Months>
                <Month key="05-22">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="04-22">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="03-22">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="02-22">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="01-22">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="12-21">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="11-21">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="10-21">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="09-21">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="08-21">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="07-21">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="06-21">
                    <PaymentStatus>*</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="05-21">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="04-21">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="03-21">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="02-21">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="01-21">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="12-20">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="11-20">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="10-20">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="09-20">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="08-20">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="07-20">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="06-20">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
            </History24Months>
            <BranchIDMFI>5507</BranchIDMFI>
            <KendraIDMFI>55070073</KendraIDMFI>
            <DaysPastDue>0</DaysPastDue>
            <TypeOfInsurance>C</TypeOfInsurance>
            <InsurancePolicyAmount>20000</InsurancePolicyAmount>
        </Account>
        <Account seq="3" id="2142432866" ReportedDate="2022-05-17">
            <AdditionalMFIDetails id="2142432866">
                <MFIClientFullname>USHA</MFIClientFullname>
                <MFIDOB>20-01-1982</MFIDOB>
                <MFIGender>Female</MFIGender>
                <MFIIdentification>
                    <MFIVoterID>YEE0585182</MFIVoterID>
                </MFIIdentification>
                <MFIAddress>
                    <AdditionalAddressDetails seq="1">
                        <MFIAddressline>ANUGUL DISTRICT-DHAR STATE-MADHYA PRADESH 456771</MFIAddressline>
                        <MFIState>MP</MFIState>
                        <MFIPostalPIN>456771</MFIPostalPIN>
                    </AdditionalAddressDetails>
                </MFIAddress>
                <Phone seq="2" typeCode="H">
                    <Number>7000931043</Number>
                </Phone>
                <MemberId>1354156</MemberId>
            </AdditionalMFIDetails>
            <AccountNumber> 13962539</AccountNumber>
            <CurrentBalance>45228</CurrentBalance>
            <Institution>Annapurna Finance Private Limited</Institution>
            <PastDueAmount>0</PastDueAmount>
            <DisbursedAmount>55039</DisbursedAmount>
            <LoanCategory>JLG Individual</LoanCategory>
            <LoanPurpose>AGRICULTURE</LoanPurpose>
            <SanctionAmount>55039</SanctionAmount>
            <LastPaymentDate>2022-05-13</LastPaymentDate>
            <DateReported>2022-05-17</DateReported>
            <DateOpened>2021-12-01</DateOpened>
            <LoanCycleID>1</LoanCycleID>
            <DateSanctioned>2021-11-29</DateSanctioned>
            <DateApplied>2021-11-29</DateApplied>
            <AppliedAmount>55039</AppliedAmount>
            <NoOfInstallments>24</NoOfInstallments>
            <RepaymentTenure>Monthly</RepaymentTenure>
            <InstallmentAmount>2850</InstallmentAmount>
            <KeyPerson>
                <Name>RADHESHYAM</Name>
                <RelationType>Husband</RelationType>
            </KeyPerson>
            <Nominee>
                <Name>RADHESHYAM</Name>
                <RelationType>Husband</RelationType>
            </Nominee>
            <AccountStatus>Current Account</AccountStatus>
            <History24Months>
                <Month key="05-22">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="04-22">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="03-22">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="02-22">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="01-22">
                    <PaymentStatus>000</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
                <Month key="12-21">
                    <PaymentStatus>NEW</PaymentStatus>
                </Month>
            </History24Months>
            <BranchIDMFI>233</BranchIDMFI>
            <KendraIDMFI>55831</KendraIDMFI>
            <DaysPastDue>0</DaysPastDue>
            <TypeOfInsurance>L</TypeOfInsurance>
            <NumberOfMeetingsHeld>0</NumberOfMeetingsHeld>
```

Here is my query which separates each account into different rows.

```
Select,XmlData2.a.query('.') as xmlDoc2
from  t_CBResponseBatchDetail l 
      cross APPLY l.ResponseReceivedData.nodes('//InquiryResponseType/*:ReportData/*:AccountDetails/*:Account') AS XmlData2(a)
```

Expecting output like;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXxLN.png)

Comment: `CROSS JOIN` <> `CROSS APPLY` and neither are functions.

Comment: Aside... XML namespaces are kind of important. Have you considered using them instead of wildcarding?

Answer (score 0):

Every XML element resides in a namespace, even if that's the anonymous namespace. When elements define or reference particular namespaces you need to ensure that you use those same namespaces when querying the data.

Here's the long-winded version, defining namespace URIs inside the XPath expressions:

```sql
select
  account.value(N'@seq', N'int') as seq,
  account.value(N'@id', N'int') as id,
  account.value(N'@ReportedDate', N'date') as reporteddate,
  account.value(N'declare namespace rpt="xxxxx"; (rpt:AdditionalMFIDetails/rpt:MFIClientFullname/text())[1]', N'nvarchar(100)') as MFIClientFullname,
  try_convert(date, account.value(N'declare namespace rpt="xxxxx"; (rpt:AdditionalMFIDetails/rpt:MFIDOB/text())[1]', 'nchar(10)'), 105) as MFIDOB,
  account.value(N'declare namespace rpt="xxxxx"; (rpt:AdditionalMFIDetails/rpt:MFIGender/text())[1]', N'nvarchar(100)') as MFIGender
from t_CBResponseBatchDetail l
cross apply l.ResponseReceivedData.nodes('
  declare namespace rpt="xxxxx";
  /InquiryResponseType/rpt:ReportData/rpt:AccountDetails/rpt:Account
') AS totallyUnimportantNameHere(account);
```

Luckily SQL Server has the [with xmlnamespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/with-xmlnamespaces) clause so that you can define namespace URIs just once:

```sql
with xmlnamespaces(
  'xxxxx' as rpt
)
select
  account.value(N'@seq', N'int') as seq,
  account.value(N'@id', N'int') as id,
  account.value(N'@ReportedDate', N'date') as reporteddate,
  account.value(N'(rpt:AdditionalMFIDetails/rpt:MFIClientFullname/text())[1]', N'nvarchar(100)') as MFIClientFullname,
  try_convert(date, account.value(N'(rpt:AdditionalMFIDetails/rpt:MFIDOB/text())[1]', 'nchar(10)'), 105) as MFIDOB,
  account.value(N'(rpt:AdditionalMFIDetails/rpt:MFIGender/text())[1]', N'nvarchar(100)') as MFIGender
from t_CBResponseBatchDetail l
cross apply l.ResponseReceivedData.nodes('/InquiryResponseType/rpt:ReportData/rpt:AccountDetails/rpt:Account') AS totallyUnimportantNameHere(account);
```

Both of these statements are equivalent and return the same results:

| seq | id | reporteddate | MFIClientFullname | MFIDOB | MFIGender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1589243954 | 2022-04-30 | USHA USHA | 1982-04-09 | Female |
| 2 | 1604629720 | 2022-05-04 | USHA | 1982-04-09 | Female |
| 3 | 2142432866 | 2022-05-17 | USHA | 1982-01-20 | Female |